# How to keep the session started in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

When I close the application in which I am working, the user loses the session, ie if they close the app the user has to enter again the data of email and password.

I do not have the least of this because the event happens, but there is some specific function of accounts-password or accounts-base that allow me to keep the session only break the login when user indicates `Meteor.logout ()`.

Comment: if you look in the users collection, you should see a resume token (or tokens) for each user. these keep track of login state and the normal behavior is the user does *not* have to enter credentials across app re-starts. if your users do, then something is wrong.

Comment: Ok, there must be something wrong because this is happening, do you recommend me some way to verify and get the problem? @zim

Comment: By default the user should stay logged in to a Meteor app even after window close.

Comment: @Marcelrama, i don't know what's wrong, but i would start by verifying that the user collection has the resume tokens in there.

Comment: Ok thanks I will continue to investigate to see that it may be that that is causing me to exit the session. @zim

Comment: This session token is saved in your browser localStorage. Any change your browser is configured to not store any browsing data (e.g. incognito mode)?

Comment: Hello, I have a flow router with a line that sent me to redirect to my initial template always starting with them I started the initial view which I thought I had left the session.

Comment: If you have an answer for this, please post it in the answer section below, thanks!

Comment: My problem was related to flow router had in all my routes the code that left the main post, what I did was delete from each of the routes I had created.Let me know if it works @halfer

Comment: @Marcelrama: I am not looking for an answer for myself. I'd like to encourage you, if possible, to write an answer, if you believe that would be helpful for future readers. Comments here are temporary, answers are forever `:-)`.

Comment: Aha, you've edited the solution into the question - we don't do that here. I've moved it to the answer box, if you can do that in future, that would be great!

Comment: Ok thanks for the information  @halfer

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Here is my answer:

```js
FlowRouter.route('/home', {
    name: 'home',
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
      if (!Meteor.userId()){
          FlowRouter.go('index');
        } else {
          FlowRouter.go('/');
        }
      BlazeLayout.render('homeLayout', {
        header: "Header",
        main: "homeView",
        footer: "menuTabs",
      });
    }
});
```